# MongoDB does not save timestamps

Tags: mongodb, go

I need to save the timestamps for `createdAt` and `updatedAt` properties in the database, but they are not being saved automatically, they are being saved as `{T: 0, I: 0}`. I am using [Mongo Driver](https://go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver) to perform CRUD operations.

So, this leds me to another problem while attaching the current time to the user model; I read somewhere that both `createdAt` and `updatedAt` have to be `primitive.Timestamp`, but I don't know how to really save them.
I have tried `User.CreatedAt =` with:

- `time.Now()`
- `new primitive.Timestamp(time.Now(), 1))`
- `primitive.Timestamp{ T: uint32(time.Now().Unix()), I: 0 }` (this seems to be working)

Getting back to the main problem, the best solution should be that the database allows me to configure the timestamps to be saved automatically whenever a `insertOne()` is triggered.
That could work always that assigning `primitive.Timestamp` to `User.CreatedAt` is correct.

So, this is my model:

```golang
package models

import (
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
)

type User struct {
    Id           primitive.ObjectID  `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Email        string              `bson:"email" json:"email"`
    CreatedAt    primitive.Timestamp `bson:"createdAt" json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt    primitive.Timestamp `bson:"updatedAt" json:"updatedAt"`
}
```

And this is my service:

```golang
func CreateUser(user models.User) (models.User, error) {
    db := database.GetDatabase()
    result, err := db.Collection(collection).InsertOne(context.TODO(), user)
    if err != nil {
        return models.User{}, err
    }

    user.Id = result.InsertedID.(primitive.ObjectID)
    user.CreatedAt = primitive.Timestamp{ T: uint32(time.Now().Unix()), I: 0 }
    return user, nil
}
```

So, it is ok to manage the timestamps like this or did I just mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `time.Time`:

```
type User struct {
    Id           primitive.ObjectID  `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Email        string              `bson:"email" json:"email"`
    CreatedAt    time.Time `bson:"createdAt" json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt    time.Time `bson:"updatedAt" json:"updatedAt"`
}
```

MongoDB does not update these for you. You have to set them yourself before storing them in the DB:

```
user.CreatedAt=time.Now()
user.UpdatedAd=user.CreatedAt
result, err := db.Collection(collection).InsertOne(context.TODO(), user)
```